# Implementing custom menu in android system

Tags: android, customization

I am trying to find a way to customize the android menu in system level.I want to remove the existing android menu and replace the custom menu.Can any one done the replacement of default menu.Can any one help me how to do that?? or kindly share some useful links to do that.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope these links will be helpful to you,

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/android/AndroidMenusMyWay.aspx

[Adding Custom Menu In Messege Activity in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394852/adding-custom-menu-in-messege-activity-in-android)

[Android: customize application's menu (e.g background color)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593529/android-customize-applications-menu-e-g-background-color)

Comment: Hi Raghu, I had implemented this.But It will work only for applications which is using this menu.I want to replace the default menu in the entire system.So that newly installed application also can use the same menu .

Answer (score 0):

check this:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html

Comment: Hi Vinith,I want to replace the android system menu itself.