# android how to make menu icon side by side with title

Tags: android, menu

how to make the menu icon display at beside of the title like below the action bar picture?
[image: action bar]

this is my program picture, is it possible to do it? please help~thanks

[image: my program]

here is my code

```
public void openOptionsMenu() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    super.openOptionsMenu(); 
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //call the base class to include system menus
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        int group1 = 1;
        MenuItem bakchome = menu.add(group1,1,1,"Add News");
        bakchome.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_add);

    return true;
}

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            ProgressDialog progress1 = new ProgressDialog(News.this);
            progress1.setMessage("Loading...please wait..");
            progress1.setTitle("Planbiz");
            new MyTask(progress1).execute();
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News_Edit.class);

            startActivity(intent1);
            break;

        }

    return true;
}
```

sorry i am new user, can not upload the picture. sorry if i can't explain my question very well.

Comment: then you can use your own custom designs

Comment: how can i change the menu icon position ?i saw this kind of question here but they asking the action bar

Answer (score 1):

You want your menu item to appear in the action bar I presume?

Add this to your menu item:

```
android:showAsAction="true"
```

Comment: i want the layout like action bar in my bottom menu

Comment: You want an action bar at the bottom of your screen? You can't put one in the menu.

Comment: i want do the menu bar at the bottom and the icon with text is side by side like the action bar picture i show above

Answer (score 1):

this may help you

[Implementing custom menu in android system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7239126/implementing-custom-menu-in-android-system)

they also talks about customizing menus

Comment: seem they not doing the bottom menu..they talking about action bar is it?